# Problem with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is problem with it do not stop at first but continues to the third rules, the problem is just here.; There is several line rules and ending with rules that manage that does not fit on anything.

When I disable 3rd rules will */news* not work but now, rules 1 works.

There are not any problems with the second rules.

I have gone through whether there is a loop through the query after *news2.php?readmore=$1* and then on news2.php ask for news_cats.php, that is not the case.

I've also been looking at whether there is a loop in the htaccess file that is not the case.

What is problem?

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/[^/]*/?$ news2.php?readmore=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news_category/([0-9]+)/[^/]*/?$ news_cats.php?cat_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news news_cats.php [L]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of one which fails, with the actual result you get?

Comment: As @mrab suggested, it would be useful if you provide example url's that are causing you problems.

Comment: [News](http://olddevils.dk/news) - [Read a news](http://olddevils.dk/news/1/OldDevils_dk_Hjemmesiden) as you can see it just go for the news_cats.php; news - But the second rules works fine; news_category [News category](http://www.olddevils.dk/news_category/3/Spil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooooh I've found the error. It is a loop in the htaccess.

3 rules news will fit not only news, but it would also capture the file "*news*"2.php

The solution.

```
RewriteRule ^news(?!2\.php) news_cats.php [L]
```

Comment: Can not see the forest for the trees.